# <img> doesn't transform inside the <figure> element

Tags: css, image, transform, transition, figure

I want to scale image inside figure on `:hover` with `transition:transform`, but `#image` doesn't react.

HTML:

```
            <h1 id="title">Leo Tolstoy</h1>
            <p class="subtext" id="subheader">An extremist with a cool beard</p>
            <figure id="img-div">
                <img id="image" src="tolstoi-portrait.jpeg"/>
                <figcaption id="img-caption"    
                class="subtext">Tolstoy thinking about salvation</figcaption>
            </figure>
```

CSS:

```
#img-div{
    background-color: var(--color-pink);
    border-radius: 5px;
    padding:2rem;
    padding-bottom:0;
    margin:1rem auto;
}

#img{
    display: block;
    transition: transform 1s;
}

#img:hover{
    transform: scale(1.05,1.05);
}
```

Why `transform` works great for container `<figure>`, but not for nested `<img>`?

[How it looks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aaQXD.png)

Comment: As far as I can see you need to use `#image` in your CSS instead of `#img` as you use that id inside the `<img>`...

Answer (score 0):

The `#img` doesn't have a transform, at least on your example. Transforms are not inherited.

On your markup i don't see an element with `id="img"`, which is what you target with `#img { ... }` on your css.

If you want to target the `<img>` element, than you can write `img { ... }` on your css (without the `#`)

Also, it would be a good idea for you to use classes instead of ids to styles your elements

you can change your html to add a class to your image, for instance